# How to extract data from an API in json

Tags: json, api

I am trying to create simple code to fetch data from an api which contains the price of bitcoin and store it. I am new to json and have tried everything I could think of. Here is the code.

```
await getRemoteData('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd')
      .then((response) => {
          
        const data = JSON.parse(response);
        const price = ${data.value};
        
        
      })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

JSON looks something like `{"foo": "bar"}` so it's basically collection of strings and values. in order to get value from some json say value of key "price", in js you need to parse JSON string to JSON Object first (which you already did by `const data = JSON.parse(response);`) and get the price by:-

```
const price = data.price // assuming that the key is "price"
```

if you want some other value with different key, say key is "foo" then you can fetch the value by `let valueOfFoo = data.foo`

Comment: Thanks. How do I find the key?

Comment: just print whole json once?